# Bot becomes slow over time in loop

Tags: bots, botframework

I have a case where my bot repeatedly asks quiz questions and the custom prompt ends only when the user fails to answer correctly or times out. If I clear all conversation data with the user, initially the interaction is very smooth but as I go over 50 questions or so, it becomes slower and slower till the point where the bot is unusable. There is a noticeable amount of lag between the time the person clicks the button and the button click is acknowledged. This would be the code for my custom prompt. Any ideas what is happening

See this [VISUALLY HERE](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2479)

```
'use strict';

const
    builder = require('botbuilder'),
    engine = require('./engine'),
    emoji = require('node-emoji'),
    strings = require('./madmathstrings')

const
    MADMATH_ROUND_TIMEOUT = parseInt(process.env.MADMATH_ROUND_TIMEOUT) || 10,
    MADMATH_ROUND_TIMEOUT_BUFFER = parseInt(process.env.MADMATH_ROUND_TIMEOUT_BUFFER) || 2,
    DIALOG_NAME = 'madmath'


module.exports.beginDialog = function (session, options) {
    session.beginDialog(DIALOG_NAME, options);
}

module.exports.create = function (bot) {
    let prompt = new builder.IntentDialog()
        .onBegin(onQuestion)
        .onDefault(onAnswer);
    bot.dialog(DIALOG_NAME, prompt);
}

function onQuestion(session, args) {
    /**Record start time for logging purposes */
    let start = new Date().getTime()
    let buttons = []
    let dialogData = session.dialogData

    /**What is the difficulty level, 0 or 1 or 2 */
    dialogData.difficulty = args ? args.difficulty : 0

    /**The current index of the question */
    dialogData.index = args ? args.index : 0

    /**A maximum value used to generate random numbers below it */
    dialogData.max = args ? args.max : 10

    /**A minimum value used to generate random numbers above it */
    dialogData.min = args ? args.min : 0

    /**The total points scored by the user so far */
    dialogData.score = args ? args.score : 0

    /**Text indicating the level number */
    let level

    /**Check if it is the 5th question, 10th question, 15th ... */
    if ((dialogData.index + 1) % 5 === 0) {

        /**Increase the difficulty level by 1 so that it goes from 0 to 1 or 1 to 2 or 2 to 0 */
        dialogData.difficulty = (dialogData.difficulty + 1) % 3
        dialogData.min = dialogData.min + 1
        dialogData.max = dialogData.max + 5
    }

    /**Displays Level 0 on top of the 1st question*/
    if (dialogData.index === 0) {
        level = `Level 1`
    }
    /**Displays level N at the top of every 5th question */
    else if ((dialogData.index + 1) % 5 === 0) {
        level = `Level ${((dialogData.index + 1) / 5) + 1}`
    }

    /**No levels are displayed for intermediate questions */
    else {
        level = ''
    }

    /**Get the minimum and maximum as negative or positive numbers in a random fashion */
    let min, max

    /**a positive min number and a positive maximum number  */
    if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 1) {
        min = dialogData.min
        max = dialogData.max
    }

    /**A negative minimum number and a negative maximum number */
    else {
        min = -dialogData.max
        max = -dialogData.min
    }

    /**Generate a Math problem with 3 choices for an answer at the given difficulty level in the range supplied by minimum and maximum */
    let question = engine.puzzleMath(3, dialogData.difficulty, min, max)

    /**Convert the choices from Number to String to be used inside a button */
    question.choices.map(
        item => buttons.push(
            new builder.CardAction.imBack(
                session, item.toString(), `  ${item.toString()}  `
            )
        )
    )

    /**Send the question with the level information if available, the index and the Math expression along with a countdown timer as GIF attachment */
    session.send(new builder.Message(session)
        .text(level ? level + '  \n' + strings.question : strings.question, dialogData.index + 1, question.expression)
        .addAttachment(
        new builder.AnimationCard(session)
            .media([{
                profile: "image/gif",
                url: 'https://media.giphy.com/media/l3q2silev6exF53pu/200w.gif'
            }])
            .buttons(buttons)
        ))

    /**Store the question to be referenced later while checking for an answer */
    dialogData.question = question

    /**Record the current time as the time when the question was presented to the user*/
    dialogData.startTime = new Date().getTime()

    /**Record the end time for running all the code inside this method for logging purposes */
    let end = new Date().getTime()

    console.log(`${(end - start) / 1000} seconds`)
}

function onAnswer(session) {

    /**Record start time of this method for logging purposes */
    let start = new Date().getTime()
    let dialogData = session.dialogData, guess, isCorrect, isValid, onTime = false, speedMultiplier = 0

    /**Get the time when the user sent the answer */
    dialogData.endTime = new Date(session.message.timestamp).getTime()

    /**Find the difference between the time the user saw the question and answered it */
    let duration = Math.floor((dialogData.endTime - dialogData.startTime) / 1000)

    //If the difference is less than 5 seconds, we give a 1000 points
    if (duration <= MADMATH_ROUND_TIMEOUT_BUFFER) {
        speedMultiplier = 10;
        onTime = true;
    }

    //If the difference is between 5 - 15 seconds, we give them 100 points per second of speed
    else if (duration < MADMATH_ROUND_TIMEOUT + MADMATH_ROUND_TIMEOUT_BUFFER) {

        /**
         * If the total timeout is 10 seconds and we have a buffer of 5 seconds,
         * we calculate 10/10 * (10 + 5 - 7) = 8, 8 x 100 = 800 gives the number of points to be assigned to the user for this answer
         */
        speedMultiplier = (10 / MADMATH_ROUND_TIMEOUT) * (MADMATH_ROUND_TIMEOUT + MADMATH_ROUND_TIMEOUT_BUFFER - duration)

        /**The person has answered on time */
        onTime = true;
    }

    //Assign the user 100 points at the 15th second
    else if (duration === MADMATH_ROUND_TIMEOUT + MADMATH_ROUND_TIMEOUT_BUFFER) {
        speedMultiplier = 1
        onTime = true;
    }

    //The person did not answer on time
    else {
        speedMultiplier = 0
        onTime = false
    }

    /**The value entered by the user */
    guess = builder.EntityRecognizer.parseNumber(session.message.text)

    /**Check if the user answered the question correctly */
    isCorrect = dialogData.question.answer === guess

    /**Check if the answer is a number */
    isValid = !isNaN(guess)

    /**If the person answered with the correct number on time */
    if (isCorrect && isValid && onTime) {

        /**Increase the index of the question */
        dialogData.index++;

        /**Increase the score of the user so far */
        dialogData.score = dialogData.score + speedMultiplier * 100

        /**Fire the next question */
        session.replaceDialog(DIALOG_NAME, dialogData)
    }

    /**If the person did not answer on time */
    else if (!onTime) {

        /**How late is the person after 15 seconds */
        let howLate = duration - (MADMATH_ROUND_TIMEOUT + MADMATH_ROUND_TIMEOUT_BUFFER)

        /**Get the delay message to be shown to the user */
        let text = strings.timeout(howLate)

        /**Show a GIF image representing timeout */
        let message = new builder.Message(session)
            .attachments([
                new builder.AnimationCard(session)
                    .title(text.title)
                    .subtitle(text.subtitle)
                    .media([{
                        profile: "image/gif",
                        url: 'http://media1.giphy.com/media/26uTt2zN11nFuyH1C/200w.gif'
                    }])
            ])
        session.send(message)

        /**End the round indicating the score and the longest streak */
        session.endDialogWithResult({
            score: dialogData.score,
            streak: dialogData.index
        })
    }

    /**If the person answered incorrectly or with an invalid response */
    else {

        /**End the round indicating the score and the longest streak */
        session.endDialogWithResult({
            score: dialogData.score,
            streak: dialogData.index
        })
    }

    /**Record end time of this method for logging purposes */
    let end = new Date().getTime()
    console.log(`${(end - start) / 1000} seconds`)
}
```

Am I leaking data anywhere. Any ideas how I can resolve this increasing amount of delay

**UPDATE 1**

I tried this after setting autoBatchDelay to 0 and the problem still remains

Comment: Do you clear after every question?

Comment: @Rocket6488 no i dont, i am testing this on the emulator and am clearing the data only when i see the lag, also why i would i clear it. I am using the deleteUserData system activity on the emulator but given that there are only 2 variables that keep getting updated after each round, I dont understand where the lag s creeping from

Comment: I see in your visual that the old data is left behind, and therefore has to be accounted for in other actions to it. If you could clear that, but keep the data, then maybe it'll help clear up the lag

Comment: the prompt runs inside a dialog = dialogData, as far as session.userData is concerned, I am not adding anything but if you are saying that there is a lot of leftover stuff on the screen as i keep scrolling down, i am not sure how to clear that, also clearing the userData would erase everything, their profile, their previous interactions if any with the bot, there is a couple of properties that i need: name, age, gender, timezone etc along with their highest scores so far and longest streaks

Comment: @PirateApp I wonder if it might just be the emulator slowing down. I made a simple echo bot with no data storage or anything and after about 150 requests it starts to get slow too.

Comment: I also made an app that emulates your app, and got similar slow down after about 100 messages. However, I noticed that the console window running node prints its output very quickly after a button is pressed, while the emulator window takes several seconds to update. Are you getting similar results? That would further support that it's an emulator issue.

Comment: @mgbennet I am seeing this issue on both the emulator and the device. The time to compute my business logic has remained constant between 0.000 to 0.001 seconds taking 0.002 seconds at max and very rarely, I measured the performance of my logic. After N iterations in the loop, the time to process the button click and the time to acknowledge it keep going up making the bot unusable at some point in time unless the user clears the data. If you test your loop on messenger, you would see the same thing happening. let me know what other insight I can offer in this problem. Thank you